# How to modify the webservice provider output format from xml to JSON in Lotus notes 8.5?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, lotus-notes

Greetings!

I am writing a provider webservice (using WS provider designelements) in lotus notes 8.5. Presently it outputs the data in xml format. But the Webservice consuming system is accessible through mobile browser and needs the output in JSON format. How to modify the output format from xml to JSON?

Regards,
Sundar.

Answer (score 4):

Web services is SOAP in Domino only. If you require a REST service there are number of things you can do.

- Create a normal web agent and write your output in JSON.
- Use the URL shortcuts to read a document/view in JSON (R7.02 onwards). For example:

  `http://server.my.lan/database.nsf/viewName?ReadViewEntries&outputformat=JSON`
- You can use the [Domino Data Services](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api) (R8 onwards).
- Use XPages JSON RPC component. Part of ExtLib (UP1/openNtf R8.5.x, built in R9). Some details on it [here](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8CJARU). Also an [example here](http://domino8.strandplatsen.se/openntf/xpagesext.nsf/REST_Home.xsp).

Personally I'd go with the XPages JSON RPC component, as it offers the best level of control and ease in security.